# Printing reports in angular 4 business apps

Tags: javascript, css, angular, report

I'm developing an angular 4 business app which depend on reports, in order to print a page in html i have to separate it into its own html page with no heading or navigation to print it with style and charts using `window.print();`

Now, how can i do the same thing but within the app itself without navigating to a separate page , and what is the best practices of doing this.

Note that each report has some styling and charts that requires external libraries to be generated.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the question...  But when they click the print button why not generate the chart in a hidden area (`display:none`) and then have separate css styles for the print where you hide the navigation and show the chart with the `@media print` media query.

Comment: You can use Chrome's devtools to emulate print media queries and edit it however you want to.